# Recovering from Android app being killed

Tags: android

What's happening:

1. I open my app and then press the home button to leave it for a moment.
2. I go into `Settings > Applications > Manage Applications > Running`, find my app in the list of cached backgrounded apps, and stop it.
3. Then I hold down the home button and select my app in the list of recent apps, to run it again.

[Note: These steps are just my way of forcing the same symptoms that testers are seeing  -- they're just going in and out of the app normally, not forcing it shut.]

It opens at the activity I left it in, but in a bad state.  The first problem was that the memory holding user info was gone (which makes sense if the app is killed).  I solved that by making the User class serializable and storing the current user object in `onSaveInstanceState`, then loading it back up in `onCreate`.  Similarly, I had to recreate my `ClientConnectionManager` to get networking to work again.

The 'reloaded' activity runs just fine and I can navigate to and use *newly created* activities, but if I instead hit the back button to get back to an activity that was created before I forcefully stopped the app, I get an exception saying that the User class doesn't exist (ClassNotFoundException, apparently when doing an unparcel).

Why is this happening?  What is the correct way to handle the case when the app is killed yet still knows which activity to go back to upon reopen?  What is the name of this state where the app isn't running but isn't completely shut down?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. You can specify which activities will appear on "Recent apps" and make sure to include only the main `Activity` or any other "safe" `Activity` (`android:excludeFromRecents`)
2. You can recognize the "launched from history" case by looking for [`FLAG_ACTIVITY_LAUNCHED_FROM_HISTORY`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_LAUNCHED_FROM_HISTORY) in your launching `Intent`

Comment: I can try playing with these, but it's important to me that my activity can be returned to. My activity is launching up again well now, it's just that activities in the back stack are crashing upon launch.

Comment: Can you describe the relation between your Activity and the previous Activity? Are you passing a value or result?

Comment: This was happening for any of my activities because I was always putting a serializable (and not parcelable) user object into the bundle when saving state. I've added a solution discussing this. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4):

When an application is terminated (either by the OS or forcefully by the user), the complete activity stack is cleared. So there are no activities in the back stack, and when you start it afresh, the activity in the foreground is the only activity in the back stack. So you can't go *back* from the top of the stack. It can also happen that the back stack is cleared leaving only the root activity as mentioned in [Tasks and Back Stack](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/tasks-and-back-stack.html)

> If the user leaves a task for a long time, the system clears the task of all activities except the root activity. When the user returns to the task again, only the root activity is restored. The system behaves this way, because, after an extended amount of time, users likely have abandoned what they were doing before and are returning to the task to begin something new.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be my situation. The stack still exists -- when I hit 'back' the previous activity in the stack launches (and crashes as described). I think this quote from the docs applies in my situation: "When the system stops one of your activities (<cut>), the system might destroy that activity completely if it needs to recover system memory. When this happens, information about the activity state is lost. If this happens, the system still knows that the activity has a place in the back stack, but when the activity is brought to the top of the stack the system must recreate it"

Answer (score 1):

The solution was to make my User class implement `Parcelable`.  For reasons I don't understand, I could put my user in the `Bundle` as a `Serializable` object when saving instance state and pull it out successfully when the last visible activity was restored, but when an activity in the back stack relaunched it wasn't able to handle that object being in that bundle.

Now my app recovers from being killed while in the background.  I'm upvoting @avimak and @Rajesh because both answers taught me a lot.  Thanks.